# Vue cant work with data from composable function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, async-await, vuejs3

In my case i want to check if the user has subscribed to my product via stripe and firebase.

To archive this i wrote a composable function that checks for the current subscription in the firebase collection. When the user has a running subscription the composable function should return the data, if there is no subscription it should return `null`.

My problem is when i call the composable function in my vue component i cant use the returned data because it always is returning `null`. I when i do `console.log(subscription.value)` i get the right value inside of the composable function but `null` in my vue component.

How can i access my data inside of the vue component?

**The composable function:**

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import { db, auth } from "../../firebase/config";
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

export function useCurrentSubscription() {

    const isLoading = ref(false);
    const subscription = ref(null);
    const subscriptionType = ref(null);

    async function fetchSubscription() {
        isLoading.value = true;
        const subRef = collection(
            db,
            "stripe-customers",
            auth.currentUser.uid,
            "subscriptions"
        );

        const subQuery = query(
            subRef,
            where("status", "in", ["trialing", "active", "past_due", "unpaid"])
        );

        await getDocs(subQuery).then((sub) => {
            if (sub.docs.length > 0) {
                subscription.value = sub.docs[0];
            } else {
                subscription.value = null;
            }
        });

        if (subscription.value != null) {
            var test = subscription.value.data();
            subscriptionType.value = test.items[0].price.product.metadata.plan;
        }
        isLoading.value = false;

        console.log(subscription.value) //returns the right data
    }

    fetchSubscription();

    return { subscription, isLoading, subscriptionType };
}
```

**The vue component:**

```
<template>
Help World
<template>

<script setup>
import SubscriptionPlansComponent from "../../components/subscriptionPlanComponents/SubscriptionPlansComponent.vue";
import CustomerPortalComponent from "../../components/subscriptionPlanComponents/CustomerPortalComponent.vue";

import { useCurrentSubscription } from "../../composables/stripe/currentSubscription";

const { subscription, isLoading, subscriptionType } = useCurrentSubscription();
console.log(subscription.value); //returns null all the time
</script>
```

Comment: Place the `fetchSubscription` in the returned object of the composable. And, in your component `await fetchSubscription(); // here you have data...`. Or `fetchSubscription().then(() => { /* here you have data */ })`.

Answer (score 1):

The composable returns `subscription` immediately, but the actual data is set when the async function `fetchSubscription()` is resolved. You log the value before that happens, so you get `null`. Seems to be all in order.

One way or another, you will have to use some sort of loading mechanism. Either you build it into the component directly and use the `isLoading` ref you already return. Or you could change your composable to return the promise, and use it with the [suspense builtin](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html), which will make Vue wait for the promise to resolve before rendering the component.

Here is a snippet showing how you could use `suspense` with an async component and a composable:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const useAsyncComposable = function(){
  const text = ref('not loaded')
  const load = async () => text.value = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('composable has finished loading'), 3000))
  const promise = load()
  return {text, promise}
}

const AsyncComponent = {
  template: '<div>{{ text }}</div>',
  async setup(props, { attrs, slots, emit, expose }) {
    const {text, promise} = useAsyncComposable()
    await promise
    return {text}
  }
}

const App = { 
  components: { AsyncComponent },
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <suspense>
    <template #default>
        <async-component />
    </template>
    
    <template #fallback>
      <div>Suspense fallback while waiting for async component</div>
    </template>
    
  </suspense>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you have aproaches to fix this?

Comment: I have added a snippet showing how you could use suspense. Does that work for you?